# How to ggplot using dtplyr / data.table without converting it into dataframe or tibble?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table, dtplyr

I am trying **dtplyr** & **data.table** for first time to do some **time optimization** in my existing **dplyr** code.

**Issue:** if I use **data.table / dtplyr** data object then I am unable to plot with **ggplot**. And before plotting in **pipe/chain** commands if I just convert **data.table / dtplyr** object into **tibble** then it works with **ggplot** but then it takes even more time than working with **data.frame/tibble** entirely which is shown later in this post.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dtplyr)
library(data.table)
library(scale)
library(lubridate)
library(bench)
```

**My Code attempts & time benchmarks:**

**data:**

data.frame object

```
df_ind_stacked_daily <- read.csv(url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnsnow09/covid19-df_stack-code/main/df_ind_stacked_daily.csv")) %>% 
  mutate(Date = ymd(Date))
```

data.table object

```
df_ind_stacked_daily2 <- setDT(df_ind_stacked_daily)
```

**Plot with data.table/dtplyr object:**

```
 df_ind_stacked_daily2 %>% 
    
    filter(Daily_cases_type == "Daily_confirmed",
           Date >= max(Date) - 6 & Date <= max(Date),
           State.UnionTerritory != "India"
    ) %>%
    
    group_by( Date) %>%
    slice_max(order_by = Daily_cases_counts, n = 10) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    # as.tibble() %>%
    
            ggplot(aes(x = Daily_cases_counts, 
                       y = reorder_within(State.UnionTerritory, 
                                          by = Daily_cases_counts, within = Date),
                       fill = State.UnionTerritory)) +
            geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
            facet_wrap(~Date, scales = "free_y") +
            
            geom_text(aes(label = Daily_cases_counts), size=3, color="white", 
                       # position = "dodge", 
                      hjust = 1.2) + 
            
            # theme_minimal() +
            theme(legend.position = "none") +
            scale_x_continuous(labels = comma) + # unit_format(scale = 1e-3, unit = "k")
            scale_fill_tableau(palette = "Tableau 20") +
            scale_y_reordered() +
            coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

**Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class dtplyr_step_group/dtplyr_step.**

P.S - If I uncomment `as.tibble()` in above code chunk then **ggplot** works.

---

**Code Time Benchmarks:**

1. **data.table/dtplyr** object without converting to tibble

```
library(bench)

bench::mark(
  df_ind_stacked_daily2 %>% 
    
    filter(Daily_cases_type == "Daily_confirmed",
           Date >= max(Date) - 6 & Date <= max(Date),
           State.UnionTerritory != "India"
    ) %>%
    
    group_by( Date) %>%
    
    slice_max(order_by = Daily_cases_counts, n = 10) %>% 
    ungroup() 
    # as.tibble() %>%
)
```

```
expression       min    median itr/sec
<S3: bench_expr> 2.45ms 2.75ms 320.3396
```

2. **data.table/dtplyr** object after converting to **tibble**

```
library(bench)

bench::mark(
  df_ind_stacked_daily2 %>% 
    
    filter(Daily_cases_type == "Daily_confirmed",
           Date >= max(Date) - 6 & Date <= max(Date),
           State.UnionTerritory != "India"
    ) %>%
    
    group_by( Date) %>%
    
    slice_max(order_by = Daily_cases_counts, n = 10) %>% 
    ungroup() %>%
    as.tibble()
)
```

```
expression       min    median itr/sec
<S3: bench_expr> 12.7ms 14ms   65.41098
```

3. **data.frame** or **tibble** object

```
library(bench)

bench::mark(
  df_ind_stacked_daily %>% 
    
    filter(Daily_cases_type == "Daily_confirmed",
           Date >= max(Date) - 6 & Date <= max(Date),
           State.UnionTerritory != "India"
    ) %>%
    
    group_by( Date) %>%
    
    slice_max(order_by = Daily_cases_counts, n = 10) %>% 
    ungroup()
)
```

```
expression       min    median itr/sec
<S3: bench_expr> 6.71ms 7.97ms   120.3636
```

**Question:** So How can I make **ggplot** work with **data.table / dtplyr** without converting it to **data.frame / tibble** ??

---

```
                               ############################
```

---

(**UPDATE:** Response to Answer)

Thanks @teunbrand I am mostly using your code below & added another function along & have put it in 3 scenarios:

I have created two functions: **(1)** That performs processing & do no coerce to tibble, **(2)** That coerce it to tibble after processing.

And I ran these in 3 scenarios overall - **(1)** data.table, **(2)** data.table converted to tibble after processing, **(3)** using tibble from beginning

```
# 1. function doesn't convert to tibble 
fun <- function(x) {
  x %>%
    filter(Daily_cases_type == "Daily_confirmed",
           Date >= max(Date) - 6 & Date <= max(Date),
           State.UnionTerritory != "India"
    ) %>%
    
    group_by( Date) %>%
    
    slice_max(order_by = Daily_cases_counts, n = 10) %>% 
    ungroup() #%>%
    # as_tibble() # Always coerce to tibble
}

# 2. function convert it to tibble after all processing
fun_to_tbl <- function(x) {
  x %>%
    filter(Daily_cases_type == "Daily_confirmed",
           Date >= max(Date) - 6 & Date <= max(Date),
           State.UnionTerritory != "India"
    ) %>%
    
    group_by( Date) %>%
    
    slice_max(order_by = Daily_cases_counts, n = 10) %>% 
    ungroup() %>%
    as_tibble() # Always coerce to tibble
}


# Make data larger
dt  <- do.call(rbind, rep(list(as.data.table(df_ind_stacked_daily)), 20))
tbl_df <- do.call(rbind, rep(list(as_tibble(df_ind_stacked_daily)), 20))

# Run data.table on single thread
setDTthreads(1)
```

For unknown reasons my benchmark didn't run simultaneously so I had to run them one by one.

```
(bm <- bench::mark(
  dt_res = fun(dt), # bench dt
  min_iterations = 20
))

expression       min    median itr/sec    mem_alloc
<S3: bench_expr> 4.35ms 6.05ms   148.1923 5.12KB
```

```
(bm <- bench::mark(
  dt_to_tbl_res = fun_to_tbl(dt), # bench dt converted to tibble at end
  min_iterations = 20
))

expression       min    median itr/sec    mem_alloc
<S3: bench_expr> 65.8ms 72.2ms   12.28566 47.6MB
```

```
(bm <- bench::mark(
  tbl_res =  fun(tbl_df),   # bench tbl
  min_iterations = 20
))

expression       min    median itr/sec  mem_alloc
<S3: bench_expr> 55ms 67.8ms   13.70603 47.4MB
```

**Objective:** My main objective was to incorporate this into **shiny app** which has **dynamic variable selection** so wanted to optimize it with **data.table**.
But I guess there is no way for **ggplot** to work with **s3 objects / data.table**.

And only time difference I am getting is when I use **data.table** & pass it as **data.table** otherwise there is no benefit.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few observations to be made here:

1. As far as I understand dtplyr, along your piping chain it accumulates operations that aren't evaluated, they are just translated from dplyr to data.table syntax. Until you realise your pipe as a data.frame, data.table or tibble, your computer doesn't run the operations. This *under*estimates the runtime of your first benchmark.
2. Because you're using `setDT` to convert a data.frame to a data.table, what you are benchmarking as a data.frame is not a benchmark for a data.frame. If you read the documentation of `?setDT`, you'll see that the object is converted *in memory* and *without copying* meaning that your `df_ind_stacked_daily` is also a data.table.
3. The data.table package makes use of multiple threads by default. We should prevent this to make a fair comparison.
4. Your first filtering operation goes from medium-sized data (75748 rows) to small (252 rows). The majority of your pipe, you are not working with a lot of data, which is where data.table shines.

Adjusting for some of these things, I find that there is no difference in speed.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(dtplyr)
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
library(bench)

df <- read.csv(url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnsnow09/covid19-df_stack-code/main/df_ind_stacked_daily.csv")) %>% 
  mutate(Date = ymd(Date))

fun <- function(x) {
  x %>%
    filter(Daily_cases_type == "Daily_confirmed",
           Date >= max(Date) - 6 & Date <= max(Date),
           State.UnionTerritory != "India"
    ) %>%
    
    group_by( Date) %>%
    
    slice_max(order_by = Daily_cases_counts, n = 10) %>% 
    ungroup() %>%
    as_tibble() # Always coerce to tibble
}

# Make data larger
dt  <- do.call(rbind, rep(list(as.data.table(df)), 20))
tbl <- do.call(rbind, rep(list(as_tibble(df)), 20))

# Run data.table on single thread
setDTthreads(1)

# Benchmark simultaneously
(bm <- bench::mark(
  dt = fun(dt),
  tbl = fun(tbl),
  min_iterations = 20
))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 dt           41.1ms   42.5ms      23.4    72.2MB     35.2
#> 2 tbl          40.7ms   41.5ms      24.0      71MB     36.0
plot(bm)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @teunbrand for putting in so much efforts, details & explanation. I have tried your code & added another `function` along and `updated` them in the post `(UPDATE: Response to Answer)`. Basically I wanted to optimize this for my dynamic `shiny` plots but if `ggplot` doesn't accept `data.table` then the whole point is gone.

Comment: ggplot2 does accept regular data.table objects, it's just that dtplyr wraps data.tables in another class with `lazy_dt()` that does not go directly into ggplot2 because it has unevaluated computations that get resolved upon coersion. The `?lazy_dt` documentation explains a bit more.

Comment: Ohhh I see, that means working entirely in `data.table`  instead of `lazy_dt()` for `shiny` plots can be really fruitful for time optimization.

Comment: I don't think it will make as much of a difference with this size of data: data.table is [benchmarked](https://h2oai.github.io/db-benchmark/) on millions of rows. The most time consuming step in your code is probably the filtering and you may have some minor speed benefit in your do the `Daily_cases_type == "Daily_confirmed"` step first instead of simultaneously.

Comment: yes for this single plot alone it may not be alot but I have multiple plots on a shiny page which are created from multiple datasets.  So combined time save from all of them may may reduce initial page loading time by few seconds. And I may not be using large data now but may be in future I should consider this approach for larger datasets. And I forgot to say it earlier that I really appreciate your help in learning this.

Comment: Thank you for this interesting discussion and solution. I will definitively try it.
I don't subscribe to the concept of "fair comparison". In my opinion, the criterion is the response time of the calculation, i.e. the time the user waits for the result. If all the solutions are identical in terms of time when using a single thread, that's fine. If a solution allows multithreading, that's the one I'll choose.